# Can't compile my system in Qsys

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, nios, qsys

When trying to assemble the system according to the instructions in this document
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2013/4840/lab3.pdf
I get this error message:

```
Error: System.nios2_qsys_0: Reset slave sram_0.avalon_slave_0 not connected to instruction_master.
Error: System.nios2_qsys_0: Exception slave sram_0.avalon_slave_0 not connected to instruction_master.
Error: System.sram.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated clock
Error: System.sram.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated reset
Error: System.leds.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated reset
Error: System.nios2_qsys_0.data_master: leds.avalon_slave_0 (0x0..0x3f) overlaps jtag_uart_0.avalon_jtag_slave (0x0..0x7)
Error: System.nios2_qsys_0.instruction_master: leds.avalon_slave_0 (0x0..0x3f) overlaps jtag_uart_0.avalon_jtag_slave (0x0..0x7)
Error: System.sram.avalon_slave_0: sram.avalon_slave_0 must declare an associated reset
Error: System.leds.avalon_slave_0: leds.avalon_slave_0 must declare an associated reset
Warning: System.leds.reset: Interface has no signals
Warning: System.sram: sram.conduit_end must be exported, or connected to a matching conduit.
Warning: System.leds: leds.conduit_end must be exported, or connected to a matching conduit.
Warning: System.jtag_uart_0: Interrupt sender jtag_uart_0.irq is not connected to an interrupt receiver
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the document uses SOPC Builder, you would need to make certain changes so that it works with QSys without errors.

I have listed the fixes for the errors in your question below:

1. **Error:** System.nios2_qsys_0: Reset slave sram_0.avalon_slave_0 not connected to instruction_master.

   **Error:** System.nios2_qsys_0: Exception slave sram_0.avalon_slave_0
   not connected to instruction_master.

   **Fix**: Connect `avalon_slave_0` of the `sram` to the `instruction_master` of the `nios2_qsys` processor.
2. **Error:** System.sram.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated clock

   **Error:** System.sram.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated reset

   **Fix**: Edit the `de2_sram_controller.vhd` file and add the following lines to the signal declarations:

   `signal clk: in std_logic;`

   `signal reset_n: in std_logic;`

   Then, edit the `sram` component you created in QSys and add the `clk` and `reset_n` signals.
3. **Error:** System.nios2_qsys_0.data_master: leds.avalon_slave_0 (0x0..0x3f) overlaps jtag_uart_0.avalon_jtag_slave (0x0..0x7)

   **Error:** System.nios2_qsys_0.instruction_master: leds.avalon_slave_0 (0x0..0x3f) overlaps jtag_uart_0.avalon_jtag_slave (0x0..0x7)

   **Fix:** In the QSys window, go to `System` --> `Assign Base Addresses`.
4. **Error:** System.leds.avalon_slave_0: Interface must have an associated reset

   **Error:** System.sram.avalon_slave_0: sram.avalon_slave_0 must declare an associated reset

   **Error:** System.leds.avalon_slave_0: leds.avalon_slave_0 must
   declare an associated reset

   **Fix:** Edit the `sram` and `led` components. Under the `Interfaces` tab make sure `Associated Reset` has a `reset` signal (shown in the image below).

[image]

5. **Warning:** System.leds.reset: Interface has no signals

   **Fix:** Edit the `led` component. Under the `Interfaces` tab, towards the bottom, click `Remove Interfaces With No Signals`.
6. **Warning:** System.sram: sram.conduit_end must be exported, or connected to a matching conduit.

   **Warning:** System.leds: leds.conduit_end must be exported, or connected to a matching conduit.

   **Fix:** In the QSys window, for both the `sram` and `led` components, under the `Export` column, ensure you `Double-click to export`.
7. **Warning:** System.jtag_uart_0: Interrupt sender jtag_uart_0.irq is not connected to an interrupt receiver

   **Fix:** Ensure that the `avalon_jtag_slave` of the `jtag_uart_0` is connected to `IRQ 31`. Refer to the image below and double-click the white circle connecting the `jtag_uart_0` to `IRQ 31`.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Because in the latest version of Quartus, QSys has replaced SOPC.

Comment: Try it out first with SOPC Builder. Then you after you get it working, you can use QSys. I tried it out with SOPC Builder and it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the `sram` custom component. It only has a conduit and an Avalon-slave interface, its reset and clock inputs are not visible since the declaration of the component itself is apprently incomplete.

These problems could possibly be fixed by editing the custom component. Right-click the `sram` component (left pane), `Edit` ->  `Interfaces` (tab), make sure each interface has a clock and a reset assigned. Once done, generate the component with a new version number, and in Qsys upgrade the component to the edited version (`System` -> `Upgrade IP cores...`). Then make sure to connect the clock and reset ports for the `sram` which should now be visible in Qsys.

There are similar problem with the `leds` custom component.

It is possible or probable that the above problems are due to trying to use components for SOPC Builder in Qsys

There are also problem with overlapping base adresses. This can be fixed by `System` -> `Assign Base Adresses`.

There is an unconnected interrupt as well - scroll right in Qsys so you see the Interrupts column and connect the interrupt between the JTAG UART to the Nios processor.